# Perl calling function getting an error

Tags: perl, function, syntax-error

```
    function cal(sal); 
{

  if ($attendance eq $good && $rating eq $good ^ $average)

{

  return ( $calsal = $sal + 0.2 * $sal );

  print  "salary = $calsal\n";


  }

  else 

  {

  return ( print "employee is not worthy\n");

};
```

Getting Error as below:

```
cant locate object method "function" via package "cal" <perhaps you forgot to load "cal">? at txt.pl line 30, <employee_cost> line 2
```

Please can anyone suggest.

`employee_cost.txt` details:

```
name, department, attendence, rating, sal
A, HR, bad, bad, 1000
B, Sales, good, good, 3000
C, Admin,bad, average, 1500
D,Admin, bad,average, 2000
E,Contract temp, good, average, 2000
F, production, good, bad, 1500
```

Comment: You can't just make syntax up and expect it to work. Perl has an extensive manual in which you can find all the details; it can be a little hard to find things but the manual is well written and very thorough.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you meant `sub` (the Perl keyword for subroutine/function).  The [Perl subroutines](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_subroutines.htm) tutorial is a good place to begin.

Answer (score 1):

Your function definition is not valid Perl syntax.

1. The necessary keyword in Perl is `sub` rather than `function`.
2. There is no simicolon `;` after the function's name or the function block.
3. Standard Perl 5 knows no function signatures (number, type and name of function arguments). Instead read your variables from `@_`.

Also you first `return` from the function and then do some calculation. It doesn't seem to be useful to return the result of `print`--instead you can save the result, print it and return it. I've change it to

1. do the calculation,
2. print the result and then
3. return the result.

You've pasted only part of your code but this fixes your function definition. I've also improved your code formatting.

```
sub cal {
   my ($sal) = @_; # could also write: my $sal = shift @_;

   if ($attendance eq $good and $rating eq $good ^ $average) {
       my $calsal = $sal + 0.2 * $sal;
       print  "salary = $calsal\n";
       return $calsal;
   }
   else {
       print "employee is not worthy\n";
       return; # return no value
   }
}
```

PS: You're using the *binary* operators `&&` and `^` in your `if` clause. I am sure you should `and` instead of `&&` because you're connecting to conditions. Beware that `and` and `&&` are not the same and behave differently. Rule of thumb: Unless you're doing binary calculations and probably know exactly what you're doing, you'll probably most often need `and` or `or`. I am not quite sure about the `^`--it is *binary* xor. Maybe better use `xor`?